# Kubernetes installation using ansible fails for admin.conf not found

Tags: ansible, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup Kubernetes cluster on `Ubuntu-18.04` systems using ansible with below playbooks.

**kube-dependencies.yml**

```yml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: ssh
  
  tasks:
   - name: Make the Swap inactive
     command: swapoff -a 

   - name: Ensure net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is set to 1
     sysctl:
      name: net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
      value: 1
      state: present

   - name: Ensure net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables is set to 1
     sysctl:
      name: net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables
      value: 1
      state: present
              
   - name: Install Docker
     apt:
       name: docker.io
       state: present
       update_cache: true

   - name: Installing Prerequisites for Kubernetes
     apt: 
       name:
         - apt-transport-https
         - ca-certificates
         - curl
         - gnupg-agent
         - vim
         - build-essential
         - software-properties-common
       state: present       

   - name: Enable service docker, and enable persistently
     service: 
       name: docker
       enabled: yes
         
   - name: Add Kubernetes apt-key
     apt_key:
       url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
       state: present

   - name: Add Kubernetes' APT repository
     apt_repository:
      repo: deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: 'kubernetes'

   - name: Install kubelet
     apt:
       name: kubelet=1.19.4-00
       state: present
       update_cache: true

   - name: Install kubeadm
     apt:
       name: kubeadm=1.19.4-00
       state: present
       
   - name: Enable service kubelet, and enable persistently
     service: 
       name: kubelet
       enabled: yes
       
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: Install kubectl
     apt:
       name: kubectl=1.19.4-00
       state: present
       force: yes
```

**master.yml**

```yml
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: ssh
  
  tasks:
    - name: Intilizing Kubernetes Cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 >> cluster_initialized.txt
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: cluster_initialized.txt
                
    - pause: seconds=180   
        
    - name: create .kube directory
      file:
        path: $HOME/.kube
        state: directory
        mode: 0755

    - name: Copy admin.conf to user's kube config
      copy:
        src: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        dest: /root/.kube/config
        remote_src: yes
        owner: root
        mode: 0644

    - name: Install Pod network Flannel
      shell: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml >> pod_network_setup.txt
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: pod_network_setup.txt
```

`master.yml` always fails with below error.

```
TASK [Copy admin.conf to user's kube config] *************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [master]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf not found"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
master                     : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Not sure why `admin.conf`  file not created. Have `manifests` file only.

```
~# ls /etc/kubernetes/
manifests
```

On Master server i can see the below file with given content.

```
# cat ~/cluster_initialized.txt
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.19.13
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
```

It looks some issue with `kubeadm init`. Actually specifically i want to install `Kubernetes - v1.19.4.`  So am i missing any additional configuration in playbook? Please suggest me the way to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work when you run the kubeadm init manually on the master node? add --v=5 to kubeadm that should give trace info

Comment: @HoD, Yes on `master` host manually able to install using `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 -v=5`

Comment: Does this manual install actually creates the file you are later looking for?

Comment: @Zeitounator, Yes correct manual installation created `admin.conf` file.

Comment: An now what do you get in your log file if you use the exact same debugging command from ansible ? Any error/warning regarding the configuration file creation?

Comment: Since my manual execution finished successfully. After that once I have ran my ansible playbook. It didn't return that error. I ll  remove Kubernetes and again try to install and check.

Comment: cluster_initialized.txt created on first fail and ansible never runs kubeadm init again. just delete that file on fail, fix the problem and run again.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your playbook you need to specify the version:

```bash
kubeadm init --kubernetes-version stable-1.19.4 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 >> cluster_initialized.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).